# Carousel + GridView + GridView + GridView in Scrollable in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to Flutter. I just want to make a simple app which contains a horizontal carousel, 3 gridviews with 4 item each inside a scrollable area. How to make that? means which widgets?

Do I need to use SliverList or something else?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to make such an app.For carousels you will need a package named [carousel_slider](https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider) to create carousels in flutter and you can use gridView builder widget to get a grid view.It may show error if you just use gridview.builder so we wrap it with Flexible widget.

```
Column(
            children: [
 Container(
                      child: CarouselSlider.builder(
                      itemCount: {ur_array}.length,
                      options: CarouselOptions(
                        autoPlay: true,
                        aspectRatio: 4.0,
                        enlargeCenterPage: true,
                      ),
                      itemBuilder: (context, index, i) {
                        return InkWell(
                          onTap: () {
               
                          },
                          child: ClipRRect(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                            child: Container(
                              child: Center(
                                  child: Image.network(
                                      {imageurlyouwanttoshow},
                                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                      width: 1000)),
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    )),
              Flexible(
                child: GridView.builder(
                  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                      crossAxisCount: 2,
                      crossAxisSpacing: 6.0,
                      mainAxisSpacing: 6.0),
                  itemCount: controller.datas.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                    return InkWell(
                      child: ClipRRect(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
                        child: ImageCacheing(url: controller.datas[i].imgurl!),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
```